# Kendo Grid in ASP.Net MVC: prevent refreshing data on grid.setOption

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my project I want to change grid's filter type depending on screen size. For large screens I use `GridFilterMode.Row` and for mobile devices I want to use `GridFilterMode.Menu` (`.Mobile(MobileMode.Phone)` doesn't work properly in this project and gives a very ugly result).

So I try to handle `$(window).resize` event to set the proper filter type for my grid. Here is my function:

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    var windowSize = $(window).innerWidth();
    var filterMode = "";

    if (windowSize >= 960) {
        filterMode = "row";
        loadTemplate(filterMode);

    } else if (windowSize < 960) {
        filterMode = "menu";
        loadTemplate(filterMode);
    }

});

function loadTemplate(filterModeType) {
    var grid = $("#messagesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var options = grid.getOptions();

    if (options) {
        options.filterable = { "mode": filterModeType }
        options.toolbar = [
            {
                template: $("#toolbarTemplate").html()
            }
        ];

        grid.setOptions(options);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine.
But when I call `grid.setOptions()` it causes refreshing of the grid data source, and that provokes a new request to server -  each time I change window's size. So if I resize window for 10 times - I would get 10 request!

Does anybody have an idea how to prevent this?

Just in case - my `Kendo().Grid` data source part

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
  .Read(read => read.Action("FilterTypeGrid", "Project"))
  .PageSize(20)
  .Sort(sort => sort.Add(t => t.Date).Descending())
  .ServerOperation(true)
  .AutoSync(true)
  .Model(model =>
  {
      model.Id("Key");
      model.Field(a => a.Key).Editable(false);
      model.Field(a => a.Text).Editable(false);
      model.Field(a => a.Date).Editable(false);
      model.Field(a => a.Name).Editable(true);
      model.Field(a => a.Selected).Editable(true);
  }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions):

> When setOptions is called, the Grid widget will be destroyed and
>   recreated. If the widget is bound to remote data, a new read request
>   will be made.

Kendo grid is quite complicated beast, so it needs to be rebuilt after changing options. One solution is to disable automatic data binding and provide your own mechanism or just implement caching. But why do you care? Who changes screen size in runtime? This is marginal problem and not worth spending time to solve it. Viewport size occurs mostly when phone or tablet is rotated, but one data reload is surely not a problem here.

Comment: Well, it seems that you are right. Though it's not good for me :) Thanks for help!